# How can I call a trained NN to train another NN in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a `NN`, lets call it F. Now I want to train another `NN`, lets call it G, using the following loss function: `||F(G(x))-y||`. I need to define a loss function to compute that norm. The problem is that, when I define the norm the input objects must be `TensorFlow` type and to evaluate my F (with the model.predict function) I need to give it `numpy` type input.

I have tried with the `.eval()` function that passes an input from TF type to `numpy` type, but I didn't get anything. I read that I need to define a session but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.

I post the code where I define my loss function.

Thanks!!!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
from keras.models import load_model

def loss_function(x_true,x_pred):

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(x_pred)
    #Change from TF type to numpy
    x_pred2 = x_pred.eval(session=sess) 

    #Evaluate the model
    model = load_model('model_FOR.h5')  
    y_pred = model.predict(x_pred)

    #Change from numpy type to TF
    y_pred2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred, dtype='float32')

    loss = K.mean(K.square( y_pred2 - x_true ))

    return loss
```